# Create 3d matrix from existing 2d matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, matrix, 2d

I have a 2D matrix of dimensions 64 x 727. What I would like to do is separate each of the columns, creating a 3D matrix of dimensions 64 x 1 x 727.

I have looked through several similar questions on here, but my limited matlab ability is preventing me from applying previous answers to my own issue.

Many thanks,

Robbie

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
reshape(matrix,64,1,727)
```

if that doesn't produce what you want explain further.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
x2d = rand(64, 727);
x3d = reshape(x2d, 64, 1, 727);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
permute(matrix,[1 3 2])
```

switches 2nd and 3rd dimensions