# Create 3D matrix from MULTIPLES 1xm matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, 3d

Is it possible to create 3D matrix from 1xm matrix? I would like to separate each column of the matrix into 3rd dimension. This is the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025255/create-3d-matrix-from-existing-2d-matrix-in-matlab). However, it doesn't involve multiples of 1xm matrices, which I did.

```
a=randi([1 5], [1 100]);
b=randi([1 5], [1 100]);
c=randi([1 5], [1 100]);
d=randi([1 5], [1 100]);

%this is where I wanted to split the matrix when assembling
K=[b d a;
    b 0 a;
    b c a];
```

Resultant `K` matrix should be `3x3x100`. Where in each 3rd dimension, the values of `a b c d` is their corresponding column. For example:

```
k(:,:,1)=[b(1,1) d(1,1) a(1,1);
b(1,1) 0 a(1,1);
b(1,1) c(1,1) a(1,1)];
.
.
.
k(:,:,n)=[b(1,n) d(1,n) a(1,n);
b(1,n) 0 a(1,n);
b(1,n) c(1,n) a(1,n)];
```

Any efficient way to do this?
Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `permute` to swap the vectors dimensions:

```
a=randi([1 5], [1 100]);
b=randi([1 5], [1 100]);
c=randi([1 5], [1 100]);
d=randi([1 5], [1 100]);
% permute dimensions to 1x1x100
a = permute(a,[1 3 2]);
b = permute(b,[1 3 2]);
c = permute(c,[1 3 2]);
d = permute(d,[1 3 2]);
%this is where I wanted to split the matrix when assembling
K=[b,d,a;
    b,zeros(size(a)),a;
    b,c,a];
size(K) % 1x1x100
```

you can also `permute` `K` after concat:

```
a=randi([1 5], [1 100]);
b=randi([1 5], [1 100]);
c=randi([1 5], [1 100]);
d=randi([1 5], [1 100]);
K = cat(3,[b;b;b],[d;zeros(size(a));c],[a;a;a]);
K = permute(K,[1 3 2]);
```